# What are the requirements needed to unlock the bonus dungeons?

Tags: version-differences, dragon-quest-vii

In the PS1 version, there were two bonus dungeons that you could unlock, but with the changes and additions in the 3DS version, there are more than just two now. What are the new requirements to unlock each bonus dungeon now?